# to build mozilla nss vs2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mozilla, nss

I want to build NSS 3.20 for Windows 64 bit using visual Studio 2012.  But this requires mozilla build which is a current binary for visual 2013. I have my projects in visual Studio 2012. Can anyone provide mozilla build package for vs2012? The official site of mozilla has the build for vs2013 under the link provided for vs2012.

Answer (score 0):

"Earlier versions of Visual Studio are not supported; the Firefox codebase relies on C++ features that are not supported in VS2012 or earlier." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites

I don't think what you're asking for is possible.